# Linux device not reachable during network (ping)

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a setup with my Windows PC, a switch, and a Linux SBC (not Raspberry) and I try to connect the SBC with my computer through the switch to provide internet and SSH to the SBC.

The SBC outputs the following IP adresses

```
root@imx6qpdlsolox:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.234.40  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::204:9fff:fe06:3984  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:04:9f:06:39:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 364  bytes 45484 (44.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 166  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 140  bytes 35993 (35.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 446  bytes 29426 (28.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 446  bytes 29426 (28.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My computer outputs the following

```
Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::4ece:1a02:7677:2d01%22
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.200
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.254.79.200
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.234.200
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway .
```

I can ping the SBC from my computer

```
Ping wird ausgeführt für 169.254.234.40 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 169.254.234.40: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 169.254.234.40: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 169.254.234.40: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 169.254.234.40: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64

Ping-Statistik für 169.254.234.40:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Mittelwert = 0ms
```

But not my computer from the SBC

```
root@imx6qpdlsolox:~# ping 169.254.234.200
PING 169.254.234.200 (169.254.234.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Both devices are connected via the switch. The switch confirms it and the LEDs are blinking. The green LED on the SBC isn´t blinking, but the orange does. What does this mean? I read that green means a successful link, so the board doesn´t have a link. But why is the switch then showing a successful link and why does a ping work?

Comment: I think netmask is bad. Configure your windows NIC: `169.254.234.200/16` becuase I see your linux is configure with that subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows by default comes with a firewall that blocks just about everything inbound – including even ping requests.

Run `wf.msc` on Windows, open "Incoming", and enable the built-in "ICMP Echo" and "ICMPv6 Echo" rules. They will be under "Core Network Diagnostics" in Windows 11, or under "File Sharing" in Windows 10 (the latter also limits them to same-subnet only by default).

Also, try to keep your netmasks identical for all devices on a given subnet. Currently your SBC uses `255.255.0.0`, but the PC is configured to use `255.255.255.0` for its 169.254.234.200 address. While in this case it's not *yet* causing problems (as both the SBC's and PC's addresses are still within the narrower of the two netmasks), it still very much counts as misconfiguration.

So the PC's 169.254.234.200 address should ideally be changed to use the 255.255.0.0 netmask. (The PC's other IP addresses can continue using their current netmasks.)

---

Ping is a bidirectional check that combines two things (request and reply) into a single pass/fail. If it fails, the next step is to check those things **separately,** i.e. you want to find out whether the computer is receiving the SBC's ping request without relying on the reply.

For that, packet capture tools are used (usually Wireshark for Windows/Linux GUI or tcpdump for CLI) – even if the computer doesn't respond, being able to see the request arrive at the computer will tell you that the SBC's network configuration is correct (or at least halfway correct) and therefore that it's the computer that chooses not to reply. (Or it may tell you that the computer replies through a different interface because you specified the wrong netmask...)

> The green LED on the SBC isn´t blinking, but the orange does. What does this mean? I read that green means a successful link, so the board doesn´t have a link

Ethernet LED indicators do not have a standard color scheme; what you've read about network LEDs on one device is not necessarily true for another.

For example, it could be that the SBC uses "orange = 100 Mbps" and "green = 1 Gbps", where either of the colors indicates a successful link but at different bitrates. (I've also seen the opposite, with orange indicating the faster speed.)